# How to get a polyline from a polygon in ArcGIS Server 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, vb.net

I want to get the lines of a polygon and then get the length of each line, I'm looking on how to do this, Can anyone show me some code? Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

I'm using ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 and Visual Studio .NET.

Comment: When you say "the measure of each line" do you mean M values or the length?

Comment: I mean the length

Comment: Where is the polygon - on the server in a featureclass, or on the client app only?

Comment: Is in a feature class in the server

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [REST api](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/) to formulate a url like this: http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/1/query?text=New+York&outSR=102113&f=pjson

And use either the [Silverlight/WPF sdk](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#SpatialQuery) or Json.NET to parse the rings out of the geometry, and sum up their lengths.

Comment: do you have a sample code that I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

Given the coordinates of the polygon (in order), you can use the formula found [here](http://math.about.com/library/bldistance.htm) to calculate the distance for each line in the polygon.

Comment: yeah, we tryied that but I need the length in meters, what I'm trying now is to call the measure function and pass two points as parameters, still no luck.

Comment: Are the coordinates of the 2 points in meters?  Can you attach your code?

Answer (score -2):

use **ETGEOWIZARD** extension and run Polygon to Polyline